# Using relative paths and globbing patterns (all files in folder/subfolders) in bundleconfig.json with BundlerMinifier

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, bundling-and-minification

I have an ASP.NET Core web project. I am trying to bundle a bunch of static .js files using the [BundlerMinifier package](https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier) on the bundleconfig.json file at the root of my project. The issue I have is that the .js files I want to bundle are in another project in the solution (which I'll call MainProject), so I have to use relative paths to specify them, like so:

```
"outputFileName": "../MainProject/bundles/libraryscripts.js",
"inputFiles": [
  "../MainProject/Scripts/Libraries/Angular/**/*.js",
  // more input files
],
"minify": {
  "enabled": true
}
```

When I build my project, the bundler does not give any errors and the file `libraryscripts.js` is created at the specified folder. The problem is the file is empty, which I believe is due to the globbing pattern (**/*.js). When I enumerate all the files instead of using this pattern, it works fine. What makes this more complicated is that when I don't use relative paths (no ../ at the start), it seems to work fine when using the globbing pattern.

This leads me to believe it's a problem with using relative paths in conjunction with globbing patterns. Can anyone confirm this and does anyone know a way around this? I do not want to enumerate hundreds of .js files (neither elegant nor sustainable).

Comment: Any reason why you're not just including this files in your project? This bundler is super lightweight. If you really need to grab files like this, I'd suggest moving to more robust bundler.

Comment: True, I might try another bundler. We've been using .NET standard so far, so our websites are hosted using IIS. I'm making a .NET Core project to provide an alternative way to host the websites. I could move all those files into `wwwroot` and that would work, but I want to minimize file duplication if possible. I suppose ideally this .NET Core project wouldn't have to bundle anything as those bundled files would exist in the other project, but it seems like they are generated at runtime using some IIS trickery, and thus can't be accessed when hosting on .NET Core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note: the following is a hacky workaround that I implemented -- it is not an official solution to this problem, though it may still be helpful.**

I cloned the [BundlerMinifier](https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier) project so I could debug how it was bundling the files specified in `bundleconfig.json` and see what the problem was. The issue was in [`Bundle.cs`](https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier/blob/master/src/BundlerMinifier.Core/Bundle/Bundle.cs), in particular in the `GetAbsoluteInputFiles` method. This line gets the path of the folder in which `bundleconfig.json` is stored:

```
string folder = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(FileName)).FullName;
```

The issue is that this same `folder` variable is used later when trimming the start of the paths of the files that are found:

```
var allFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(searchDir, "*" + ext, SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(f => f.Replace(folder + FileHelpers.PathSeparatorChar, ""));
```

Since the files were in another directory, the `.Select(f => f.Replace());` part didn't remove the start of the paths of the files, which meant the comparisons later failed when being matched. Thus, no files with both `../` and a globbing pattern were found.

I came up with a hacky solution for myself, but I don't think it's robust and I will therefore not contribute to the Git project. Nonetheless, I'll put it here in case anyone else has the same issue. I created a copy of `folder`:

```
string folder = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(FileName)).FullName;
string alternateFolder = folder;
bool folderModified = false;
```

Then I created a copy of `inputFile` and checked if it starts with `../`. If so, remove it and at the same time remove the last folder name from `alternateFolder`:

```
string searchDir = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(folder, relative).NormalizePath()).FullName;
string newInput = inputFile;
while (newInput.StartsWith("../"))
{
    // I'm sure there's a better way to do this using some class/library.
    newInput = newInput.Substring(3);
    if (!folderModified)
    {
        int lastSlash = alternateFolder.LastIndexOf('\\');
        alternateFolder = alternateFolder.Substring(0, lastSlash);
        folderModified = true;
    }                        
}
```

Then I use `alternateFolder` and `newInput` *only* in the following lines:

```
var allFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(searchDir, "*" + ext, SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(f => f.Replace(alternateFolder + FileHelpers.PathSeparatorChar, ""));
var matches = Minimatcher.Filter(allFiles, newInput, options).Select(f => Path.Combine(alternateFolder, f));
```

Everywhere else still uses `folder` and `inputFile`. Also note the use of the `folderModified` boolean. It is important to only remove the last folder on `alternateFolder` once since it is in a foreach loop.